# POS system and warehouse management in Magento?

Tags: extensions

We run an online store in Magento, and also a brick-and-mortar storefront where we sell our products to retail customers.  Recently we purchased a warehouse to handle inventory/processing specifically for orders in our online store.

We're looking for a way in Magento to manage our warehouse inventory separately from our storefront inventory, so that sales in the storefront decrement storefront inventory, and online sales decrement warehouse inventory.

Although there are a number of POS and warehouse extensions that both do their respective tasks well enough, finding a setup that allows for both to work in conjunction has been difficult.  My question is, are there any POS or warehouse Magento extension integrations where this kind of setup is a possibility?  I'm just looking for information as to whether such a setup is even achievable, and how.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the POS System that you are using, I can answer based on what I know and work with. Retail Pro V9 and NCR CounterPoint have the ability to track separate inventories (in Retail Pro you can even have completely different subsidiaries; segregated inventory, customers, etc.) and there are ecommerce integration options like Linked Retail eCommerce Connect that allow for connecting those separate inventories (like your store and warehouse) to the same Magento database to manage quantities, among other options.

It's worth investigating some of these outfits in regards to customizations, too, to see what more they offer "off-the-shelf", so to speak, to make sure the end product and process fits your business requirements exactly. I come from Retail Management so I get how important Operations are in business. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins available, but below one is best

http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-pos-extension.html

for Magento 2